# In The Hunger Games series, which part of our current real world becomes Panem in future?

Tags: the-hunger-games

Wanted to know if Panem is based on current real world location or just a conceptual place? Maybe in future, part of Mexico is divided to form Panem according to the story.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered before.

It's located in the remains of North-America